# Trying to see if an element has a particular CSS attribute in the style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do something like:

```
var $list = new Array();
$selector.each(function(){
  if ( $(this).has(css("position")) ){
    $list.push($(this));
  }
});
```

It doesnt seem like the way i was doing it was working.  I saw an example that looked like:

```
var bg = ('element').parents().filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('background').length > 0;
}).eq(0)
```

but i wasnt sure if thats what i should do, or if there was another way of doing it.

Comment: which particular attribute? There are ton of attributes with different set of values like background images, gradients, transforms, positioning and sizes in different metrics like px,pt,em.

Comment: i was trying to check for the position css, the LEFT, and the TOP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close... but try this..

```
var $list = new Array();
$selector.each(function(){
  if ( $(this).css("position") ){
    $list.push($(this));
  }
});
```

Even better would be to detect the type of position ie:

```
var $list = new Array();
$selector.each(function(){
  if ( $(this).css("position") == "absolute" ){
    $list.push($(this));
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment above you may want to check for something other than specific position LEFT TOP because those will come out as 0px by default so maybe check against the value rather than the actual attribute.

Also you can use `$(this).offset().left` or `$(this).position().left` for that..

Comment: the bottom one would not push though if it was not relative or one of the other valid options for 'position'

Comment: See my edit. You my be better off to check for the value of a position using position() or offset() vs a CSS attribute.

Comment: Sure thing, Though I will possibly be posting a similar yet different question in the next few minutes.  Seems like there is something im trying to do where this is just a piece of the puzzle.